# Domain can't be assigned more than 2 levels deep - Can I fix this?

Tags: apache, dns, centos

I have a VPS with root access, and I'm wondering if it is possible to assign a domain name to a directory that is further than 2 levels deep. It is an Apache server running on CentOS.

For example...

/developers/travis/clients/clientSite

The cPanel only lets me assign domains to the travis directory, no further.  Is there a configuration file that I can get to and modify so I can assign domains to clientSite directory?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#DocumentRoot) allows using any directory as document root for you site. So if you edit configuration file (for cPanel they are located in /usr/local/apache/conf/) and restart apache, it will work.
But it is not recommended to perform manual config changes, if you are using cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a VPS the correct way is install a CPanel to easy manager it.

And

On CPanel you can change the root folder of a secon domain and put the on lvl you need:

[image]

[image]

[image]